# API response got error -1004, -1001, -1020 frequently- iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, alamofire

Our users receive errors `-1001`, `-1004`, or `-1020` frequently but not at all ( about 1% of the requests). Still, I don't have any idea why it happens they have a strong internet connection at that time ( because the error detail throws to firebase crashlytics by the internet). Also, I try to make the error environment with the same request, but I can't catch it, does anyone here know why it happens?

**MORE INFORMATION**

The request is made by `Alamofire ~> 5.6.2` in the iOS device ( all of them are iPhone and there is no iPad that got this error), `NSAppTransportSecurity` is set to `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, and as I said most of the requests are successful.

Comment: So what is generating these errors, thats what you need to find out. If these are errors from the remote service, then they mean something propriatary to the end point software, but not us, without more info

Answer (score 1):

These errors are expected to happen on mobile devices. No matter how good their service is, as users move around they will have requests timeout (-1001), be unable to connect (-1004), or try to make requests with cell data disabled (-1020).

Fundamentally, this logic:

> Still, I don't have any idea why it happens they have a strong internet connection at that time ( because the error detail throws to firebase crashlytics by the internet)

doesn't hold. Not only can the connectivity of mobile devices change from one step to the next, but it's entirely likely Firebase saves error reports for later and retries failed attempts to upload them.

So none of this really seems unusual or concerning, especially if you already have robust error handling in your app.